# How to do bulk webpage redirect?

Tags: html, wordpress, redirect

Recently, I have revamped my website. Previously, I created the site in PHP so all the URL ends with .PHP Now the site is moved to WordPress and all the URL is sitename.com/about-us.

I have 1000 of pages with .PHP version. What is the best way to redirect all the .PHP pages to new pages?

Note. All .PHP pages are indexed in Google. Now I want to index all new pages.

I don't much knowledge in the backend. I am looking for an easy solution.

Comment: What type of web server are you using?  It is possible to host WordPress on Apache, Nginx or IIS.  Since the redirects will be implemented using web server configuration, and each web server does it differently, it is important to know this information to be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a redirect using the `.htaccess` file.

Example:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

P.S.: for testing `.htaccess` you can use [this site](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/).

Comment: This answer assumes that your web server is Apache and that you have configured it to use `.htacccess` with `AllowOverride All` in the configuration. It also assumes that `mod_rewrite` is installed and enabled.